# Google map with marker not displayed using the HTML5 Geolocation API

Tags: html, google-maps, model-view-controller

I tried to replicate the following example. 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-geolocation-api-tutorial-example/

I am not able to view the map other than Latitude and Longitude on the browser. Same works when I hit the "Show my location on Map" button on the link above.

Am I missing something in this HTML?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;
        function showlocation() {
            // One-shot position request.
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback, errorHandler);
        }

        function callback(position) {

            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
            document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;

            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLong
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
            map.setZoom(8);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
        function initMap() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
                zoom: 1,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"),
                                              mapOptions);

        }

        function errorHandler(error) {
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <input type="button" value="Show my location on Map"
               onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />   <br />
    </center>

    Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>       <br />
    Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <br /><br />
    <div>Map</div>
    <div id="mapdiv" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting my own key on google API and reformatting the code like below, I am able to get it working on IE and Firefox. Still on chrome, its not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
        <input type="button" value="Show my location on Map"
               onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />   <br />
               Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span>       <br />
    Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
    <br /><br />
    </center>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function showlocation() {
            // One-shot position request.
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
        }

        function callback(position) {

            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;

            document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
            document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;

            var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLong
            });

            marker.setMap(map);
            map.setZoom(8);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        }

      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_OWN_KEY_GET_FROM_GOOGLE_API_AND_REPLACE_THIS_STRING&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your post works for me.  Most likely:

- you aren't serving it from a secure domain (via https://)
- you denied geolocation at some point

The geolocation example in the linked blog also only works for me with a secure origin https://viralpatel.net/blogs/html5-geolocation-api-tutorial-example/ (at least in Chrome).

[fiddle (works for me on a computer that allows geolocation)](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/prraa7Lo/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;

function showlocation() {
  // One-shot position request.
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback, errorHandler);
}

function callback(position) {

  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lon = position.coords.longitude;

  document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = lat;
  document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = lon;

  var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latLong
  });

  marker.setMap(map);
  map.setZoom(8);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function initMap() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdiv"),
    mapOptions);

}

function errorHandler(error) {
  switch (error.code) {
    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
      alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
      break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      alert("Location information is unavailable.");
      break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
      break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      alert("An unknown error occurred.");
      break;
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#mapdiv {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<center>
  <input type="button" value="Show my location on Map" onclick="javascript:showlocation()" />
  <br />
</center>

Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span> 
<br />Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span>
<br />
<br />
<div>Map</div>
<div id="mapdiv" />
```

Comment: Do you mean, I can use it only through SSL enabled site?

Comment: I tried enabling https on my VS localhost, on IE 11. Issue seems same. On Chrome, I have some problem with https, it says cerficiate is not trusted.

Comment: You can only use it in Chrome on a secure site, other browsers (particularly IE) may not have that restriction.  Does the fiddle work for you? Does the blog example work for you? Look at the console in the browser, there should be some indication of why it isn't working.

Comment: Yes, fiddle, blog examples are working. Unfortunately I don't see any errors on console. I see following warnings.
"Google Maps API warning: NoApiKeys https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#no-api-keys" util.js:222:12
"Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required"

Answer (score 0):

your code looks good, but you need to make sure you are using SSL, or else it will not work (or visually look like it is not working). Since about a month ago, Google has enforced certifying your site with SSL if you wish to use several of their services, including but not limited to the Geo Location.

Communication is now only done [through HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro#overview). You can see more information from [April 2016 here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only?hl=en).

I mention this because I am over the past 3 months been migrating about 100 clients to SSL because of this, and even today, there are still way too many that did not listen and now are having different issues like the "Oops! Geolocation function not supported" or the Google API simply not working. But when you look at the Browser Console it mentions the reason.