# Implementing html5 Geolocation into an existing maps JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I believe this is an easy problem, I am an unexperienced user though so please walk me through the steps a bit.

The maps JavaScript API has a documentation point called 'Geolocation: Displaying User or Device Position on Maps' which shows a map that has at the top a button that pans to the user location.

This feature is what I want to implement into my existing map.

Below is a minimal working html code snippet from the map I want to implement the location finder into. The API key has been replaced by three dots and there is a JavaScript configuration file linked on line 244.

I tried adding the js example code from the documentation above and below the initMap function as html, but since the bottom api url only refers to one initMap and replacing it renders the code unusable I am stuck.

Highly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for days!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Neighborhood Discovery</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
   
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .neighborhood-discovery .map {
        bottom: 0;
        left: 20em;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }

      @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
        .neighborhood-discovery .panel {
          right: 0;
          top: 50%;
          width: unset;
        }
      }  
    </style>
    <script>
      'use strict';
      function NeighborhoodDiscovery(configuration) {
        const widget = this;
        const widgetEl = document.querySelector('.neighborhood-discovery');

        widget.center = configuration.mapOptions.center;
        widget.places = configuration.pois || [];

        // Initialize core functionalities -------------------------------------

        initializeMap();
        initializePlaceDetails();
        initializeSidePanel();


        /** Initializes the interactive map and adds place markers. */
        function initializeMap() {
          const mapOptions = configuration.mapOptions;
          widget.mapBounds = new google.maps.Circle(
            {center: widget.center, radius: configuration.mapRadius}).getBounds();
          mapOptions.restriction = {latLngBounds: widget.mapBounds};
          mapOptions.mapTypeControlOptions = {position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT};
          widget.map = new google.maps.Map(widgetEl.querySelector('.map'), mapOptions);
          widget.map.fitBounds(widget.mapBounds, /* padding= */ 0);
          widget.map.addListener('click', (e) => {
            // Check if user clicks on a POI pin from the base map.
            if (e.placeId) {
              e.stop();
              widget.selectPlaceById(e.placeId);
            }
          });
          widget.map.addListener('zoom_changed', () => {
            
          });

          const markerPath = widgetEl.querySelector('.marker-pin path').getAttribute('d');
          const drawMarker = function(title, position, fillColor, strokeColor, labelText) {
            return new google.maps.Marker({
              title: title,
              position: position,
              map: widget.map,
              icon: {
                path: markerPath,
                fillColor: fillColor,
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: strokeColor,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(13, 35),
                labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(13, 13),
              },
              label: {
                text: labelText,
                color: 'white',
                fontSize: '16px',
                fontFamily: 'Material Icons',
              },
            });
          };

          // Add marker at the center location (if specified).
          if (configuration.centerMarker && configuration.centerMarker.icon) {
            drawMarker('Home', widget.center,
                       '#1A73E8', '#185ABC', configuration.centerMarker.icon);
          }
        }
        }
    </script>
    <script src="dd-map-original.js"></script>

    <script>
      function initMap() {
        new NeighborhoodDiscovery(CONFIGURATION);
      }
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="neighborhood-discovery">
      <div class="places-panel panel no-scroll">
        <header class="navbar">
          <div class="search-input">
            <input class="place-search-input" placeholder="Search nearby places">
            <button class="place-search-button">
              <img src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/search/v11/24px.svg" alt="search"/>
            </button>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="results">
          <ul class="place-results-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <button class="show-more-button sticky">
          <span>Show More</span>
          <img class="right" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/expand_more/v11/24px.svg" alt="expand"/>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="details-panel panel"></div>
      <div class="map"></div>
      <div class="photo-modal">
        <img alt="place photo"/>
        <div>
          <button class="back-button">
            <img class="icon" src="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/i/googlematerialicons/arrow_back/v11/24px.svg" alt="back"/>
          </button>
          <div class="photo-text">
            <div class="photo-place"></div>
            <div class="photo-attrs">Photo by <span></span></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <svg class="marker-pin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="38" fill="none">
        <path d="M13 0C5.817 0 0 5.93 0 13.267c0 7.862 5.59 10.81 9.555 17.624C12.09 35.248 11.342 38 13 38c1.723 0 .975-2.817 3.445-7.043C20.085 24.503 26 21.162 26 13.267 26 5.93 20.183 0 13 0Z"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=...&callback=initMap&libraries=places,geometry&solution_channel=GMP_QB_neighborhooddiscovery_v2_cABCDEF" 
    async defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below the referenced file that is called above in line 163 under the name dd-map-original.js

```
const DEPLOYMENT_METADATA = {
    "deploymentName": "Don Det Neighborhood discovery"
  };
  const CONFIGURATION = {
    "capabilities": {"search":true,"distances":true,"directions":true,"contacts":true,"atmospheres":true,"thumbnails":true},
    "pois": [
      {"placeId": "ChIJIdUeHHEPEzERgsbd0QPdEQY"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJpxVa7woPEzERuLX4Y6Uzb-U"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJCcbODv0OEzERHs_sVemgNRc"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJrx9Xlv0OEzERwi4HoshmrWc"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJWwp_RqkPEzERFVewiUEietQ"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJVwQmEgAPEzERmzOLFomOpks"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ18hHSKoPEzERjQKYkVzUOvs"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJR-ppXQIPEzERoV4XeKPUyag"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ65L-oP0OEzERirCqNlHATkM"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ131p7AsPEzERuHp4-iIypXU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJo3Ocl_0OEzERIo2o9IGH3BQ"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJMQ12kqoPEzERu8zZDtXR5tY"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJfWGOlP0OEzER8J_IubImk1I"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJR4pYDv0OEzERBI46TaW7Wm4"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJk4wWlP0OEzERWAUn6JcOkmg"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJxZRtof4PEzER81N8YhSj1ac"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJS30TBP4OEzERjTWYaVP5V5E"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJv4YjHv4OEzER1sZ04izAmZ0"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJW54ICv0OEzERysGzxuj_W1E"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJu0IHCAYPEzERNDfVPCVTvCk"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJA0y6fKcPEzERmXU8RGL3ZWk"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJBXxfsqsPEzERkJCu9zoGqIg"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ4V_zfuIPEzERpVRTKWsJvqw"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJsbwql_0OEzERo-8MgtyDeDU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJdV7ATAEPEzERzsg22bc4SyE"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJjw8FUKYPEzERBR6SuW4TiL4"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJFwCTjocPEzERtM6YkydFHJg"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJLdNJ-vMPEzERDbi7v1oGe0k"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJe9YJpaAPEzERvw4n_28j4FI"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJY1rsBv4OEzERCpPaP5NP5-E"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJR9FagAYPEzERmzcz9AHNevk"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJW-j0pKgPEzERobkQRbGqf1A"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJZWi5ov0OEzERmQAtxv0cwtE"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ09SQ3wUPEzERS64RerNmQFE"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJf1qfVqoPEzERWJcpE5W6XMM"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJHybcWAoPEzERM_nR6Jl1vzo"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJO3x-Cv0OEzER3DFbUke2Nz8"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJQUnggv0OEzERODAepa2qZbo"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ6yyuXAIPEzER5SOkdbSYD5w"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ_1D1i6APEzERkCtnNpt9SiA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ_-AO1wEPEzERVLItx48j4eg"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJgQO4fAIPEzERrgV9XIDdC-o"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJTVrK2AEPEzERlE8YEsyAkFE"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJP3Dxov0OEzERgXr6f4i5fO8"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJmYT0u58PEzERJvGiZ0YxtrI"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJA23zlQkPEzER2CWDVXfYtNU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJkbMqXHMPEzERmbjIsKMBYWQ"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJI42khP0OEzERlzqgPPeT6d8"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJxfENiB8PEzERa1-NfzXFZnA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ9wBEDv0OEzERGZdO98yN204"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJFba89awPEzER6oTnWOAxm6A"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJfbcnbP0OEzERZrGQGSJg0hI"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJb8Gbcf0OEzERpghXlBN8xGM"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJHwSfmM0PEzEROGGN0yfgSCE"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJS68ewtoPEzERM56y-Ko8eBI"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJS3MYXQoPEzERpqUDjcbypnA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJdUXfYo8PEzERJLxdt0J5xAA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJsdXJ7_0OEzERdNCZdkWV5do"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJM9I7cf0OEzERyE04b6va1-w"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJKw2H0L0PEzERVIKQ1vrUUO0"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJP1JYFvcPEzERsRwNlephfco"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJAaukzP0PEzER4u7eGODCZV0"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJoRDKgv0OEzERwYBcmETRLuw"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJffafpIEPEzERFhQkclVswHs"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJDcMucugPEzERmPDoen_sycM"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJRaABnfUOEzERWwhWxbjyj5I"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJh_zhmqoPEzER5e5DqpVS8vA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJXWdTK1oPEzERUWNzM-VlNZQ"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJlR9YFgAPEzERHZ-G-cdXqCw"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJjbGHhP0OEzERnC-jf3SQwvA"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJlfP4VEYPEzERyu5-G7ssiMs"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ0R7ek-gPEzERjLn78LnMgDU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJKSOJHG0PEzERAGPvgVx96c4"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJG6HjnHEPEzERizNGXkvtr5U"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJF_zVgv0OEzERO24KdBQkIDU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJCyKRuAoPEzERZbnB__safz0"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ5yOPJycPEzERQiiwW4kVHN8"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJg4ZvMnsPEzERy9IpNuAeraU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJOVKDof0OEzERh-_u1JLLUZI"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJqQksmP0OEzERCruNbmz6SEs"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJHyLMNGIPEzER1lO5c35rwt8"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJfbcnbP0OEzERZEAh8UPUJh0"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJS6dRZOIPEzERPEgfSumvYtM"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJRX4X5d0PEzERDgiaVl2mcfo"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJ_____wYPEzERg6FW-a92UeU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJfZqGRtYPEzERPcORI4AAyPU"},
      {"placeId": "ChIJY7_1SBUPEzERPTO_4XUs1IM"}
    ],
    "centerMarker": {"icon":"circle"},
    "mapRadius": 4000,
    "mapOptions": {"center":{"lat":13.975873,"lng":105.9200531},"fullscreenControl":true,"mapTypeControl":true,"streetViewControl":false,"zoom":16,"zoomControl":true,"maxZoom":20,"mapId":""},
    "mapsApiKey": "..."
  };
```

Comment: What does "renders the code unusable" mean?  An javascript errors? Is this a duplicate of; [Using initMap and initAutocomplete on same html page google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085722/using-initmap-and-initautocomplete-on-same-html-page-google-maps)? With the posted code I get two errors: `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (dd-map-original.js)` and `ReferenceError: CONFIGURATION is not defined`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google map with marker not displayed using the HTML5 Geolocation API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289260/google-map-with-marker-not-displayed-using-the-html5-geolocation-api)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for helping out. I checked the other topic you mentioned and it is similar, but my question is regarding the implementation of the code not really an error problem.
'Renders code unusable' I just mean that the map shows blank and nothing works anymore.
The ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND refers to the mentioned .js config file that is called by the code around line 163. Same for the CONFIGURATION which is in the .js file.

Basically what I am looking for is someone pointing me to a line in my code to say: copy it here inside a <script> or something.

Comment: @geocodezip just added to my original post the CONFIGURATION file you mentioned that was throwing errors. To test create a .js file under the described name to run the original html code.

Comment: Now I get `ReferenceError: initializePlaceDetails is not defined`.  2nd request, please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue (preferably a [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself).

Comment: Have you read [ask]?

Comment: I have read it, it is very difficult for a newbie on this site to follow all rules while still being a newbie though. I appreciate your efforts @geocodezip! I will close the topic for now as the problem goes to hands of someone else.